# Banach Tarski proof understanding

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces

**Theorem** (Banach-Tarski Paradox): The unit ball $\mathbb{D}^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is equi-decomposable to the union of two unit balls.

**Proof**: Let $\mathbb D^3$ be centered at the origin, and $D^3$ be some other unit ball in $\mathbb R^3$ such that $\mathbb D^3 \cap D^3 = \varnothing$.

Let $\mathbb S^2 = \partial \mathbb D^3$ (Its boundary $\partial \mathbb D^3$ is
 the surface of that ball, which is a sphere. It is the bounding surface of the ball. It can be said it is the $2$-dimensional unit sphere of $\mathbb R^3$).

By the Hausdorff Paradox, there exists a decomposition of $\mathbb S^2$ into four sets $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ such that $A$, $B$, $C$, and $B \cup C$ are congruent, and $D$ is countable.

For $r \in \mathbb R_{>0}=(0,+ \infty)$, define a function $r^{*}: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ as $r^{*}(\mathbf x ) = r \mathbf x$, and define the sets:

$$    \displaystyle W = \bigcup_{0 \mathop < r \mathop \le 1} r^{*}(A)$$
$$    \displaystyle X = \bigcup_{0 \mathop < r \mathop \le 1} r^{*}(B)$$
    $$\displaystyle Y = \bigcup_{0 \mathop < r \mathop \le 1} r^{*}(C)$$
    $$\displaystyle Z = \bigcup_{0 \mathop < r \mathop \le 1} r^{*}(D)$$

Let $T = W \cup Z \cup \left\{{ \mathbf 0 }\right\}$.

Since $A$ and $B \cup C$ are congruent, then this means $W$ and $X \cup Y$ are clearly congruent, hence $W$ and $X \cup Y$ are equidecomposable.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are congruent, and $W$ and $X$ are congruent, $X \cup Y$ and $W \cup X$ are equidecomposable.

$W$ and $X \cup Y$ as well as $X$ and $W$ are congruent, so $W \cup X$ and $W \cup X \cup Y$ are equidecomposable.

Hence $W$ and $W \cup X \cup Y$ are equidecomposable, by Equidecomposability is Equivalence Relation.

So $T$ and $\mathbb D^3$ are equidecomposable, from Equidecomposability Unaffected by Union.

Similarly we find $X$, $Y$, and $W \cup X \cup Y$ are equidecomposable.

(*)

Since $D$ is only countable, but $\mathbb{SO}(3)$ is not, we have:

$$ \exists \phi \in \mathbb{SO} (3): \phi (D) \subset A \cup B \cup C $$

so that $I = \phi \left({D}\right) \subset W \cup X \cup Y$.

Since $X$ and $W \cup X \cup Y$ are equidecomposable, by a theorem on equidecomposability and subsets, $\exists H \subseteq X$ such that $H$ and $I$ are equidecomposable.

Finally, let $p \in X - H$ be a point and define $S = Y \cup H \cup \left\{{p}\right\}$.

Since:

$Y$, $W \cup X \cup Y$

$H$, $Z$

$\left\{{0}\right\}$, $\left\{{p}\right\}$

are all equidecomposable in pairs, $S$ and $\mathbb B^3$ are equidecomposable by Equidecomposability Unaffected by Union.

Since $D^3$ and $\mathbb D^3$ are congruent, $D^3$ and $S$ are equidecomposable, from Equidecomposability is Equivalence Relation.

By Equidecomposability Unaffected by Union, $T \cup S$ and $\mathbb D^3 \cup D^3$ are equidecomposable.

Hence $T \cup S \subseteq \mathbb D^3 \subset \mathbb D^3 \cup D^3$ are equidecomposable and so, by the chain property of equidecomposability, $\mathbb D^3$ and $\mathbb D^3 \cup D^3$ are equidecomposable.

---

This is a complete proof of the BT paradox which i have a lot of questions about. I think i understand everything until the (*).

What does the $\mathbb{SO}(3)$ mean???

Also if two sets are congruent, does that mean they are equidecomposable? Because it seems like that is what it is above (*).

Comment: $SO(3)$ (I have never seen it written in blackboard bold, as you did) is the group of orthogonal $3\times3$ matrices with determinant 1. Also known as the group of rotations (in Euclidean 3-space).

Comment: Aren't two sets said to be equidecomposable if each can be decomposed into $n$ pieces which can then be paired together so that each piece from one set is congruent to the corresponding piece of the other? If so, congruent sets are trivially equidecomposable (with $n=1$).

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen The formal definition for equidecomposable is: Sets $S$ and $T$ are equidecomposable if there exists a set $$X=\{Q_1, ... , Q_m \} \subset \mathcal P ( \mathbb{R}^n )$$ with $\mathcal P ( \mathbb{R} ^n )$ as the power set of $\mathbb{R}^n$  such that both $S$ and $T$ are decomposable into the elements of $X$. Would you still say that congruent sets are trivially equidecomposable?

Comment: Probably, assuming that $S$ being decomposable into the elements of $X$ means that you can write $S=P_1\cup\cdots\cup P_n$ (with the $P_i$ pairwise disjoint) and $P_i$ congruent to $Q_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.